# Use a function name that's a string in map loop?

Tags: r, purrr

Some code:

```
mymtcars <- mtcars %>% head %>% rownames_to_column('model') %>% group_by(vs) %>% nest
mymtcars
     vs data             
  <dbl> <list>           
1     0 <tibble [3 × 11]>
2     1 <tibble [3 × 11]>
```

I can fit a linear model on this list column df like so:

```
mymtcars %>% 
+   mutate(mod = map(.x = data, ~ lm(.x$mpg ~ .x$cyl)))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   vs [2]
     vs data              mod   
  <dbl> <list>            <list>
1     0 <tibble [3 × 11]> <lm>  
2     1 <tibble [3 × 11]> <lm>
```

What if my function name is a field?

```
mymtcars2 <- mtcars %>% head %>% rownames_to_column('model') %>% group_by(vs) %>% nest %>% crossing(func = c('lm'))
> mymtcars2
# A tibble: 2 x 3
     vs data              func 
  <dbl> <list>            <chr>
1     0 <tibble [3 × 11]> lm   
2     1 <tibble [3 × 11]> lm
```

I gave it a try with:

```
mymtcars2 %>% 
+   mutate(mod = map2(.x = data, .y = func, ~ .y(.x$mpg ~ .x$cyl)))
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `mod`.
x could not find function ".y"
ℹ Input `mod` is `map2(.x = data, .y = func, ~.y(.x$mpg ~ .x$cyl))`.
```

How can I pass the function to call in map and then call it in the above block?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be using `match.fun` inside map2 like below:

```
   models <-  mymtcars2 %>% 
       mutate(mod = map2(.x = data, .y = func, ~ match.fun(.y)(.x$mpg ~ .x$cyl)))
```

**Output**:

```
[[1]]

Call:
match.fun(.y)(formula = .x$mpg ~ .x$cyl)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       .x$cyl  
  36.926733    -2.728218  


[[2]]

Call:
match.fun(.y)(formula = .x$mpg ~ .x$cyl)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       .x$cyl  
    41.9400      -3.8025
```

Answer (score 3):

I also found that I can use get:

```
mymtcars2 %>% 
  mutate(mod = map2(.x = data, .y = func, ~ get(.y)(.x$mpg ~ .x$cyl)))
```

Am unsure of when to use one over the other.

Answer (score 3):

A different option could be:

```
mymtcars2 %>%
    mutate(mod = map2(.x = data,
                      .y = func,
                      ~ exec(.y, mpg ~ cyl, data = .x)))

     vs data              func  mod   
  <dbl> <list>            <chr> <list>
1     0 <tibble [3 × 11]> lm    <lm>  
2     1 <tibble [3 × 11]> lm    <lm>
```

Comment: This looks interesting. I read the documentation for exec but didn't really follow or understand it? Does it simply translate a string into it's function equivalent like it reads above or is it more nuanced than that?

Answer (score 1):

Since {dplyr} >= 1.0 this kind of problems can be solved with `dplyr::rowwise`. We can use it either with a classic `do.call`, in which case we have to wrap the arguments in `list()`, or with `rlang::exec`. With `dlpyr::rowwise` we don't need `map2` which makes things more readable since there is no lambda function with `.x` `.y`. However, since the output column stores `lm` objects (and not an atomic vector), the result has to be wrapped in `mod = list(...)`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mymtcars2 %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(mod = list(do.call(func, list(mpg ~ cyl, data = data))))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      vs data              func  mod   
#>   <dbl> <list>            <chr> <list>
#> 1     0 <tibble [3 × 11]> lm    <lm>  
#> 2     1 <tibble [3 × 11]> lm    <lm>

mymtcars2 %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(mod = list(exec(func, mpg ~ cyl, data = data)))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      vs data              func  mod   
#>   <dbl> <list>            <chr> <list>
#> 1     0 <tibble [3 × 11]> lm    <lm>  
#> 2     1 <tibble [3 × 11]> lm    <lm>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>